# How can i change UITextview content

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm fetching datas from my api and trying to write datas to UITextview but when I try this I'm getting error.

These codes are feching datas from api and write them in uitextview:

```
NSOperationQueue *apiCallsQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSString *urlstring=@"x.com/api.php?id=";
urlstring =[urlstring stringByAppendingString:self.newsId];

NSURL *newsdetail = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
newsdetailrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newsdetail];

@try
{
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:newsdetailrequest queue:apiCallsQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
        [textview setText:[dictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];
    }];
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Error"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Tamam"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
}
```

error output :

```
2013-06-18 16:37:16.214 xpro[6816:5103] bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x7142ee0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   0x3571fe9 WebThreadLock
2   0x15846e -[UITextView setText:]
3   0x5f00 __39-[NewsDetailViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke
4   0xbdbcf8 __block_global_0
5   0xb4375a -[NSBlockOperation main]
6   0xb11453 -[__NSOperationInternal start]
7   0xb11164 -[NSOperation start]
8   0xb9da31 __block_global_6
9   0x49ff53f _dispatch_call_block_and_release
10  0x4a11014 _dispatch_client_callout
11  0x4a022e8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain
12  0x4a02450 _dispatch_worker_thread2
13  0x96c53e72 _pthread_wqthread
14  0x96c3bd2a start_wqthread
(lldb)
```

here is my Controller.h

```
@interface NewsDetailViewController : UIViewController
{
NSURLRequest *newsdetailrequest;
NSMutableData *newsdetailData;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *newsdetailTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *navBarTitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *newsId;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *htmlDetail;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Dispatch into the main thread for UI updates.

```
NSOperationQueue *apiCallsQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

NSString *urlstring=@"x.com/api.php?id=";
urlstring =[urlstring stringByAppendingString:self.newsId];

NSURL *newsdetail = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
newsdetailrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:newsdetail];

@try
{
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:newsdetailrequest queue:apiCallsQueue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary =  [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
        ^{
            [textview setText:[dictionary objectForKey:@"title"]];
        });
    }];
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Error"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Tamam"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to access UIKit from a background thread, which isn't recommended.

Try this: `[textview performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"title"] waitUntilDone:YES];`

This ensures that `setText:` is called on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the error says, what happens. UI code must run on main thread. The following will fix the error. Put that in the completionHandler block.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                  //do ui operations like setting textview text
                              });
```